# Is it possible to get the HTML out of a DataList\Repeater using Ajax(Jquery)?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a asp.net page with a repeater\datalist control on it. I bind this grid during page load and show the first 20 thumbnails of a photo album.

There can be multiple pages for which I have a pager 1 2 3. When user clicks the second page(2), I go and get the second set of album thumbnails and show.

Currently this is a postback and when I show 2nd page whole page gets refreshed.

Now is it even possible to use Ajax\jquery to get the second page of htmls with all thumbnails on it and render? This way the page never has a post back and I can avoid page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- asp:UpdatePanel for your repeater

Pros: Easy to do, just  wrap your repeater with a asp:UpdatePanel control.

Cons: You will be sending a post back to the server with all the viewstate, the server runs the full page life-cycle and just retuns part of the page. Other cons [here](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)

- jQuery.load to insert just part of a page

Pros: Also very easy to implement, you would need to manage loading the correct page in you aspx page for a GET request (ie. adding ?page=2 to the query string and process that on the server side). After that you wrap the repeater in a div that you can identify on the client side and do a jQuery.load() (check the docs for it [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

Cons: you will still be sending a full page back to the client. Also if you rely on the viewstate for postbacks inside your DataList, this could screw it up.

- Pure Ajax call to get the data and render it back on the client

Pros: Optimum in terms of what gets sent back to the server and from the server to the client.

Cons: You would be replacing the DataList/Repeater with your own rendering/templating engine in the client side to make this work.

Comment: asp:UpdatePanel is not an option as I am not deploying gigantic .net ajax dlls

Comment: On your 3rd opt: say I replaced the grid with a jquery function that loops the result & build the grid. This is fine for textual data, but I have thumbnails & I just get the filepath from database. 
Your solution requires me to set the src attr of the <img> elements (jquery) to these image paths? Won't these send one separate http request to the web server for the image file?

I have 50 thumbnails per page. So I will end up sending 50 separate http reqs to the server to get the thumbnail images for each page? Not right?

I want to send just one http ajax request and get all thumbnails. Doable?

Comment: My enter button just not working. Can't add new line. So big paragraph

Comment: In any case, you end up having an http request for the html page and 50 for the thumbnails (and possibly other requests for css, scripts, etc), even in the first page request... that's just the way it works on any page. There are things you can do to decrease the number of requests like css sprites (combine several images into one image and just render part of it through css) but I'm not sure its a good solution for dynamic/"per-product" thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 has the concept of inline image data without the href required to pull the bits with a separate request.  Until v5 is here consider using jquery to GET your list of thumbnail urls given a page # as input.  With very little jquery you can repaint what you're rendering with your repeater now with the lightest possible server roundtrips.

Another optimization to implement if you're concerned about multiple image GETs is to reference your image path using a subdomain (images.yoursite.com) to get the browser to pull your images in parallel with your primary page data.  There's some odd rule that browsers use about using up to 2 concurrent threads for pulling page data but only if the sources are not located at the same root URL.